# Update Esri SOAP to REST

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-soap-api

I'm new to ArcObjects, not a GIS professional so please be patient with my lack of GIS knowledge.

I have an .Net Web application with ESRI.ARCGIS.SOAP references, looking to update them with rest.

How can I use REST in below code?

Update:
I tried to use arcgisruntime, but that was not supported in Asp.Net Web application

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.GeometryServerProxy serviceURL= new ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.GeometryServerProxy();
serviceURL.URL="Some Service URL";

ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.SpatialReference inputSpatialReference = new ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.ProjectedCoordinateSystem();
 inputSpatialReference.WKID = 3857;
 inputSpatialReference.WKIDSpecified = true;

ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.SpatialReference outputSpatialReference = new ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.GeographicCoordinateSystem();
outputSpatialReference.WKID = 4326;
outputSpatialReference.WKIDSpecified = true;

PointN pnt = new PointN();
 pnt.X = X;
 pnt.Y = Y;

Geometry[] inputGeometry = new Geometry[] { pnt };

ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.GeoTransformation geoTransformer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.GeoTransformation();
geoTransformer.WKID = 2236;

ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.EnvelopeN envelope = new EnvelopeN();
envelope = null;


Geometry[] outputGeometry = serviceURL.Project(inputSpatialReference, outputSpatialReference, false, geoTransformer, envelope, inputGeometry);

foreach (PointN item in outputGeometry)
 {
xyCoord= item.X.ToString() + "," + item.Y.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: How big is your app?  It might be easier to replace arcobjects with Esri's [.NET Runtime SDK](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_Project_1.htm), which uses REST behind the scenes.  Have you considered that?

Comment: I tried to use arcgisruntime, but that was not supported in Asp.Net Web application, can you recommend any alternative -@KirkKuykendall

Comment: Sorry, I've never tried that.  In your question you said ".NET Web Application", I incorrectly assumed you meant .NET (desktop) App that uses web services.

Comment: Is this the only bit of Esri SOAP in your app that needs replacing?

Comment: there are still other methods also, but uses same geocoder functionality-@KirkKuykendall

Comment: Did you try making a url on the server's [project html page](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=4326&outSR=3857&geometries=%7B%22geometryType%22%3A+%22esriGeometryPoint%22%2C+%22geometries%22%3A+%5B%7B%22x%22%3A+165%2C+%22y%22%3A+-20%7D%2C%7B%22x%22%3A+174%2C+%22y%22%3A+-11%7D%5D%7D&transformation=&transformForward=false&vertical=false&f=html), then replacing `f=html` with `f=pjson` then making a [c# request](https://code-maze.com/different-ways-consume-restful-api-csharp/) ...

Comment: ... and then parse the [result](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=4326&outSR=3857&geometries=%7B%22geometryType%22%3A+%22esriGeometryPoint%22%2C+%22geometries%22%3A+%5B%7B%22x%22%3A+165%2C+%22y%22%3A+-20%7D%2C%7B%22x%22%3A+174%2C+%22y%22%3A+-11%7D%5D%7D&transformation=&transformForward=false&vertical=false&f=pjson) of the [REST Project operation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/project.htm)?

Comment: yes, am currently using the same method, but not sure is it the only way to do it-@KirkKuykendall

Comment: How old is this app? Which version of ArcObjects/ArcMap/Server SDK are you using? Which version of .NET framework is app targeting?

Comment: this is wcf project, with 10.7 version and .Net is 4.6.1-@amadbear

Comment: I believe ArcObjects has been falling out of favor for sometime now, replaced with JS API, Python, etc. I agree with @KirkKuykendall in that it would be best to rewrite in REST. Of course, if the application is legacy and big, it might be difficult or not a good decision. I assume you're using the Server/Enterprise SDK of ArcObjects (not Desktop), so, have you taken a look at the documentation? Try here https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/sdk/latest/windows/webframe.html#652a31ce-4f02-43b5-bba9-9db26ce231af.html and see if you can start something using IRESTRequestHandler

Comment: IMO, using steps outlined in my earlier comment (that don't require arcobjects) would be easier than using arcobjects.